# Different behaviors while using localhost and server name

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, iis, jquery-ui-draggable

[image]I wanted to drag an image around inside a div, which I did using the jQuery UI draggable function.

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dragme').draggable();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:300px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;margin:auto;border:solid 1px black">
    <img src="http://img.thesun.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01650/greats_1650266a.jpg" id="dragme" />    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y6XVD/).
Works fine, however, the problem started when I hosted the same on IIS.
When I use http:// localhost/mysite, the page works fine on Chrome and IE, however when I use http:// servername/mysite, on IE, the page goes for a toss.
The entire image is shown on the div. [(Snapshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2IRv.png).
[image: Snapshot of the erroneous page] 
I can still drag the image around, though.

I fail to understand why this happens. I have encountered problems in the past as well where the behavior of http:// localhost/mysite and http:// servername/mysite have been different.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi can you provide your online server link?

Comment: im on intranet, sorry :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE loads local web applications in *compatibility view (IE9+)* while external websites are being loaded in IE9+ standards view. This is the reason why you see your website locally in **IE7 document mode**. You can change this by hitting F12 and changing to IE9 document mode. If you want to make your IE load local site in regular view go to `tools -> compatibility view settings` and delete localhost from there.

Comment: thanks, I'm using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,9,8,7" /> now to make it open correctly always :)