# jQuery and different browsers

Tags: jquery, html

My page on localhost requires jQuery and jQuery ui and it work on chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 11 in localhost but when uploaded my files to server jQuery ui ceases to work on Internet Explorer 11. This problem is apparently solved in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252202/different-behaviors-while-using-localhost-and-server-name) but I don't understand the answer, could anyone explain it?

My Code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge">
  <!--Here is the css file you are using for your project UI included from CDN (content delivery network)-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />

  <!--Here is the main jQuery file included from CDN.You can you any other source-->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <!--Here is jQuery UI added from CDN-->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom styles for the interface goes here -->
  <style>
  #draggable { 
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #33CCFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: verdana;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}   
  </style>

  <!-- Draggable script goes here -->
  <script>
  $(function() {
  alert();
  //Select the element of the page you want to make draggable and add the function 
  //.draggable() after that
      $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <!-- In that case this div with id of #draggable draggable here 
 and any conmonent inside that draggable div will be also draggable with that -->
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I am not sure how they did it" Did what?

Comment: So, the answer in that question didn't work?

Comment: @digitalfresh: The magic thing, I guess. :)

Comment: Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to your page.

Answer (score 1):

As of the answer of the other question the problem probably is caused by stupid IE goes on compatibility mode. You need to put this line just after the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Also you need to use `DOCTYPE`. Your HTML file needs to look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <!-- Your title, meta, link and script tags goes here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your Body tags goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

This `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag tells IE to work as latest possible version and not to enter in compatibility mode (to emulate IE7 for example).

Comment: Can you give a link to your server where you put the code to test it?

Comment: I think that the problem is in your hosting. It automatically try to put some javascript in bottom of your code (after the closing </body> tag). Maybe this javascript blocks the IE. Try another hosting provider.