# JavaScript Critical error was detected ... SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' only running on localhost, not from web server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web application with a simple JavaScript to show a 'Loading...' notice while the application retrieves content from the database:

```
    var dots = 0;
    var dotmax = 100;

    var showWait = function ShowWait() {
        var output; 
        output = 'Loading';
        dots++;

        if(dots>=dotmax)
            dots=1;

        for(var x = 0; x < dots; x++)   {
            output += '.';
        }

        mydiv.innerText =  output;
    };**

    function StartShowWait(){
        mydiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        window.setInterval('showWait',2000);
    }

    function HideWait(){
        mydiv.style.visibility ='hidden';
        window.clearInterval();
    }

    StartShowWait();
```

When I run the application from the application web server, this functionality executed without any problems. However, when I debug from localhost, I'm seeing the following JavaScript error:

> Critical error was detected at line 1, column 287 in http://localhost:42366/reports/ReportMain.aspx?RequestID=450126.
>   SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

When I click 'Continue', the application continues execution without issue.

I've been able to work around the issue by adding a ';' as per suggestion (marked with '**' in above code), but I can't understand why this extra ';' should be needed and, if it is, why the issue is only arising now. (This is an old legacy application; I have debugged this code on localhost many times and, until yesterday afternoon, I had not seen this problem; the issue did not show yesterday morning).

I'd be very grateful for any insights or advice..

Comment: the statement where the javascript compiler demands the semicolon is a variable declaration. So IMO the script error is justified, and the syntax is correct with the semicolon as you placed it.
as to why it occurs only in localhost, could it be something like localhost is in a different zone so that the whole page gets executed in context of a different compatibilty mode / corporate mode? - then, a more "tolerant" flavor of the javascript execution engine might be at work. which browser is it?

Comment: The `**` in the JavaScript code is intended?

Comment: The ** is to mark the spot where the OP added the semicolon to make it work, see Q

Comment: @ dlatikay...Unfortunately, it's IE11..

Comment: try hit F12 in both scenarios. does it tell you the same document mode (edge/compatibility, ...) in localhost case as well as in webserver case?

Comment: @ A1rPun... as dlatikay points out, the '**' is only in the script to indicate where the specified ';' has been placed to work around the problem.

Comment: `var showWait = function ShowWait() {` always annoys me.

Comment: @dlatikay... both browser instances are rendering in Edge mode. 

Your first suggestion makes sense though; it is indeed a variable declaration and should as such be closed with a ';'.

With regard to the question of why now, there does seem to have been a tightening of the rules relating to JavaScript in Edge mode. I recently completed a project to update some of our applications for IE11 (Edge) compatibility and discovered a couple of these minor script syntax errors that seem to have slipped through the cracks with IE8 and earlier.

I've upmarked your initial response... Thanks for help.

Comment: @dlatikay If I see questions with errors I always try to parse the code with my eyes and try to spot the error. I should have read the question first :)!

Comment: @ epascarello...
I'm no expert in JS; in fact I'm quite new to it, this code was written by another developer, it's origins forever lost in the mists of time ;)

I am curious though, why is var showWait = function ShowWait() { annoying, bad practice, wrong?

Comment: consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252202/different-behaviors-while-using-localhost-and-server-name its rather old (about IE versions 7 and 9) but the principle of how localhost and webserver sites behave differently might still apply.